# Is this CA store related to Ubuntu or OpenSSL

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, openssl, x.509

I am checking TLS certificates chain validity against CA sore in this path:

```
etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and OpenSSL 1.1.0g. I need to know whether this CAs store is from Ubuntu or OpenSSL?

Comment: OpenSSL has no own CA store. The most likely is that this path is the one shipped with Ubuntu in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` but since you are showing a relative path the real path this resolves to depends on your current working directory which is unknown.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the path. It starts from the etc that is under the Computer (with hard disk symbol in Ubuntu 18.04. I think this is called the root directory?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSL has no own CA store although it has a default location where it will look for a CA store. On Debian/Ubuntu this default location is `/usr/lib/ssl/certs` which is a link to `/etc/ssl/certs`.

The file `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` (note the leading '/' since this is an absolute path) is created from the certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs` using the [update-ca-certificates](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html) program which is part of Ubuntu and Debian and run automatically on installation and when needed on software updates. The certificates which are in `/etc/ssl/certs` by default are part of the [ca-certificates](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ca-certificates) package.